# How to deploy Vuejs/NodeJS app to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `nodejs`/ `vuejs`-app which I want to deploy to `heroku`. My folder structure is this:

```
app (root)
  - auth
  - client (vuejs code with /dist folder af npm run build)
    - dist
      index.html
      - static (with js and css files)
  - models
  - routes
  app.js
  server.js
  package.json
```

So, I created an app in Heroku and followede the instructions on Heroku but for some reason it doesn't succeed for me to get the app running. I even tried tried to follow [this](https://codeburst.io/quick-n-clean-way-to-deploy-vue-webpack-apps-on-heroku-b522d3904bc8) instruction but with no luck. I could imagine it has to something to do with my folder structure since I wonder how Heroku should know which files to run, since the Vue-app is inside the client folder.

Another thing is, that the Vuejs app is dependent on connecting to an API which is defined liked this by using `axios`

```
export default() => {
  return axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:3000`, (this is the port the server.js is creating)
  headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
   }
 })
}
```

I guess Heroku will not understand thsi either.

Can someone maybe give me a hint or clue?

Comment: heroku runs the `start` script defined in your `package.json`. In the link you posted you are deploying a node server which is going to serve static html/css/js generated by webpack.

Comment: Also you will need define config vars to hold value for apiEndpoints, in your case, url of your app. You can define these in `config/prod.env.js` for production environment.